# How to Display "No Items found" in a Datagrid

Tags: wpf, windows

```
               <dg:DataGrid.Resources>
                        <ViewModel:SmartMessenger  x:Key="Noitemsfound">
                        </ViewModel:SmartMessenger>
                      </dg:DataGrid.Resources>
                 <dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                          <StackPanel>`enter code here`
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource         Noitemsfound }, Path=pNorecords,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                          </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                 </dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Here i am trying to bind  a textblock that will display a message when there are no items in the datagrid . I am using VS 2008 Express edition.
The problem is am not able to bind the property Noitemsfound with a code behind class  SmartMessenger  ... Whats missing here???

Comment: Title is not the same as tags.

Answer (score 5):

if you just want to display a message in your datagrid when there are no items - you can do this with a style. Put this style in your App.xaml Resources or at least in your datagrid Resources.

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ItemsControl}" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <TextBlock Text="no items" 
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}"
                                       FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize}"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <TextBlock Text="no items" 
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}"
                                       FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize}"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGrid}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}}">
</Style>
```

Comment: Your code looks perfect  ... But its not working for me.. i guess because i am binding the datagrid in the code behind and not setting the Itemssource attribute od datagrid in XAML... LIKE

Comment: DtGrid.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, Bind)

Comment: Can I know how to notify the textblock to display message based on binding in the code behind ?

Comment: it should work no matter how you bind the itemssource. pls post you whole xaml for your datagrid.

Comment: sorry,Actually i forgot to tell you one thing i am not compiling the xaml, i am parsing it..

Comment: This works but it messed up my normal styling when there are items somehow (headers now have white background somehow). Is there a way to use this but keep whatever styling was already present?

Comment: I found that adding  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}} to the ItemsControl style helped but I still lost my headers and have a weird white background below the grid display.

Answer (score 1):

Check output window. WPF dumps binding error/exception occurred to output windows. There you gets the chance to verify if it is binding to right source, if path is correct etc.

You can also try adding dummy converter in the binding expression. Converter provides you chance to debug binding expression

Comment: Observable collection you must be using to bind data to grid. You should write trigger on grid items count. If this count is zero or null, you should apply 'NoItemFound' template to grid.