# Add "No Record Found" row to a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to add a row to my DataGrid when the ItemSource is empty. Aka - when no data is returned.

I have tried the solution for this question

[How to Display "No Items found" in a Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157152/how-to-display-no-items-found-in-a-datagrid)

But it sets the background of the DataGrid to show a message and not a new row.

I also tried

[Show "No record found" message on a WPF DataGrid when it's empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687414/show-no-record-found-message-on-a-wpf-datagrid-when-its-empty)

But to no avail. (The row doesn't show up even after I apply the style)

I just want to display an empty row containing the words "No Record Found". Is it possible?

Comment: Add a dummy record to your data collection?

Comment: @Niclas but my grid is configured so it can hide columns, so the actual message would get hidden if I hide that field.

Comment: If you don't like adding the message as an overlay and you can't add it as actual data you are kind of running out of options. Are adorners out of the question aswell? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Niclas, but I ended up using a label overlay on the grid.