# LinqToSql ...query without no data

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

i have this query build with Linq as follow

```
var query15 = (from g in dc.Fix_Hotel_TTVs
               from f in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs
               where g.CityCode == "KEP" && g.MarketID == "IT" && g.Category == "DEL" && g.HotelCodeID == f.HotelCodeID
               select new { Code3 = f.WholeCode == ""? "No Data" : f.WholeCode, Hotel3 = f.HotelName == "" ? "No Data" : f.HotelName }).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

Well i want show in the DataGrid in case the result of the query is null in the fields **Code3**  and  **Hotel3** the string ="NO Data" but i can not find out the solution to have this result ,then do you have any idea how to work out this issue?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Is that WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy ...it is for WPF...thanks for the interest!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think hard-coding UI constants in SQL query is not very good idea. Just handle that case in UI. I.e. you should have query in your Data Access layer:

```
var query =  from g in dc.Fix_Hotel_TTVs
             join f in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs // you can use join
                  on g.HotelCodeID equals f.HotelCodeID
             where g.CityCode == "KEP" && 
                   g.MarketID == "IT" && 
                   g.Category == "DEL"
             select new FooViewModel { // Consider to create class for this data
                 Code3 = f.WholeCode,
                 Hotel3 = f.HotelName
             };
```

Then bind data returned from Data Access layer to DataGrid. Also provide default row with `No Data` text as described in following questions:

- [Show “No record found” message on a WPF DataGrid when it's empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219208/show-no-record-found-message-on-a-wpf-datagrid-when-its-empty?lq=1)
- [How to Display “No Items found” in a Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157152/how-to-display-no-items-found-in-a-datagrid)

Answer (score 1):

You should supply the default values to the DefaultIfEmpty method:

```
public class HotelGridViewModel
{
    public string Code3{get;set;}
    public string Hotel3{get;set;}
}

var query15 = (from g in dc.Fix_Hotel_TTVs
           from f in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs
           where g.CityCode == "KEP" && g.MarketID == "IT" && g.Category == "DEL" && g.HotelCodeID == f.HotelCodeID
           select new HotelGridViewModel() { Code3 = f.WholeCode, Hotel3 = f.HotelName 
           ).DefaultIfEmpty(new HotelGridViewModel(){ Code3 = "No  Data", Hotel3 = "No Data"});
```

Answer (score 1):

i think a simple solution...
for example i have a two field name and family:
and my query is:

```
var query=(from p in behzad.main_table
select p).toArray();
```

and simple decode your query for example

```
for(int i=0;i<query.count();i++){
if (query[i].name=="Empty or Null")`
dt[i]["name"]="your message for show in gridview"
```

when your for complete
simple fill datatable into gridview for example

```
gridview.datasource(dt);
```

TNX